# Remove all DOM children except branch PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I have a DOM (structure no matter).

```
<g>
    <svg>
        <g><path/></g>
        <g><circle/></g>
    </svg>
</g>
```

I need to remove all svg children that haven't `path` element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this XPath expression:

```
//svg[not(.//path)]
```

which will get all `svg` elements without a `path` descendant.

You can also use

```
//svg/*[not(.//path)]
```

to get only the actual children of `svg` elements that are not `path`.

Then, just delete all matches from the XML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($doc);
$x = new DOMXPath($dom);
$toDelete = $x->query("//svg[not(.//path)]");
foreach ($toDelete as $child) {
    $child->parentNode->removeChild($child);
}
var_dump($dom->saveXML());
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/6kKYI)

*edit* changed from with path element to without path element, thanks @splash58 for the heads up

Comment: svg children that haven't path = `$toDelete = $x->query("//svg/*[not(.//path)]");`

Comment: Crap, I misread the question. Edited it, thanks for the heads up @splash58 !

Comment: children - svg`/*`

Comment: @splash58 oh, do you understand it to mean only to remove the children that are not path? I read it as “delete the whole Svg element if it doesn’t have a path child”

Comment: he wrote `remove all svg children`. He wants to remove `<g> without `path`

Comment: @splash58 I see. I’m having a little trouble understanding exactly what he mean (I actually read it as “Svg elements without path children”), maybe because of my English. I added that option just in case, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

In Jquery:

`$("g > svg > g:not(path)").remove();`

Comment: This appears to be a fine JavaScript answer, but be careful; this won't help the asker (which is probably why it was downvoted). Note that they tagged the question with PHP, so they're looking for a way to accomplish this in PHP.